# Move a schema from one AWS RDS to another

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-sct

I need to move a schema and its objects from one AWS RDS to another AWS RDS database.
I have used the AWS schema conversion tool (SCT) in the past.

Is there a better way or is what I am doing the best?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Database Migration Service (AWS DMS) will help you to migrate databases to AWS quickly and securely. The source database remains fully operational during the migration, minimizing downtime to applications that rely on the database. The AWS Database Migration Service can migrate your data to and from the most widely used commercial and open-source databases.

Here is the reference link which will help you to guide further for [AWS DMS](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/)

Comment: I do not need any conversion. It is migrating from same DB/version to another same DB/version.